# App starts bluetooth advertising only when in background on iphone 4s

Tags: ios, background, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have a somehow strange problem... I have developed a BLE app which works fine as it should on iPhone 5/5S and iPad3. But on iPhone 4s it has a strange behaviour:

In my app I am advertising data via CBPeripheralManager, but the iPhone seems not to advertise the data. But it starts advertising the data as soon as the app is going to background and any other app is in foreground.

Has anyone had the same issue?

At the moment it feels like a bug. But may be there are some differences on how to setup advertising on iPhone 4s and newer devices.

As mentioned the code is working fine on other devices, only iPhone 4s seems to have the issue.

Any feedback is valuable!

Thanks
Sascha

Comment: There is no difference in setting up the advertising, all I can think of is some sort of thread blocking - possibly to do with the different processor on the 4s vs the other devices.  Have you tried the LightBlue app?  You can set it up as a peripheral and also use it to scan in central mode

Comment: Can you tell when you invoke the `startAdvertising` method and whether there is any difference between the order on the 4S and the other devices? This issue is most probably some overlook in your app but it's hard to tell without any exact info.